# why does fluentd is not starting?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, fluentd

I tried as per your document, But I am getting this error

2019-02-12 21:17:32 +0530 [error]: config error file="/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf" error_class=Fluent::ObsoletedParameterError error="'host' parameter is already removed: Use  section instead."

what it means?

Comment: When I am trying to start the fluentd forworder in application server, i am getting  this error.    Job for td-agent.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status td-agent.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

Comment: First, please check your td-agent.conf.
Please show me your full configuration when you get errors and tell me your td-agent version.

Comment: Thank you for your response okkez, i solved that error. i changed the td-agent.conf file as below.

Comment: Where is the td-agent.conf ?